# R, how to increment the a for loop limit within the loop itself?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am working in R and I am trying to change the limit of a for loop within the loop itself, but I cannot succeed.

Here's my toy peace of code:

```
setwd(".")
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
cat("\014")
set.seed(11)


execution_limit <- 10

for(exe_i in 1:execution_limit)
{
    cat("(exe_i = ", exe_i," / ", execution_limit,  ")\n", sep="")
    Sys.sleep(0.1)

    if(exe_i == 7) {
            execution_limit <- 15
    }
}
```

Printed output:

```
(exe_i = 1 / 10)
(exe_i = 2 / 10)
(exe_i = 3 / 10)
(exe_i = 4 / 10)
(exe_i = 5 / 10)
(exe_i = 6 / 10)
(exe_i = 7 / 10)
(exe_i = 8 / 15)
(exe_i = 9 / 15)
(exe_i = 10 / 15)
```

The loop stops after 10 iterations, but I would like to go on until the 15th iteration.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: If the number of iterations isn't fixed, you can use a `while` or `repeat` loop instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I use `while`? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `while` loop like this (note that you must increment `exe_i` yourself)

```
execution_limit <- 10
exe_i <- 1
while(exe_i <= execution_limit)
{
    cat("(exe_i = ", exe_i," / ", execution_limit,  ")\n", sep="")
    Sys.sleep(0.1)

    if(exe_i == 7) {
            execution_limit <- 15
    }
    exe_i <- exe_i + 1
}

# (exe_i = 1 / 10)
# (exe_i = 2 / 10)
# (exe_i = 3 / 10)
# (exe_i = 4 / 10)
# (exe_i = 5 / 10)
# (exe_i = 6 / 10)
# (exe_i = 7 / 10)
# (exe_i = 8 / 15)
# (exe_i = 9 / 15)
# (exe_i = 10 / 15)
# (exe_i = 11 / 15)
# (exe_i = 12 / 15)
# (exe_i = 13 / 15)
# (exe_i = 14 / 15)
# (exe_i = 15 / 15)
```